# Как ждать пока очередь станет непустой?

Tags: python

Как ждать пока очередь (`Queue.Queue`) станет непустой, не изменяя ее (т.е. дергать get/put не пойдет)? Типа блокирющего `queue.wait()`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

**Никак**, если в кишки не лезть, что не следует делать. [Возвращение `False` из `queue.empty()` метода не гарантирует, что последующий `queue.get()` не заблокируется](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.empty).

Это подсказывает, что понятие "непустой" не очень полезно для очереди и следует сделать шаг назад и переформулировать задачу, принимая во внимание контекст (big picture).

Можно рассмотреть подходит ли [простой более высокоуровневый интерфейс, предоставляемый `multiprocessing.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool). Или наоборот [следует использовать `threading.Condition` напрямую](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects):

```
# Consume an item
with cv:
    cv.wait_for(an_item_is_available)
    get_an_available_item()
```

Comment: Смысл всего этого - я не хочу дергать производителя, не будучи уверенным,  что в очереди найдется место. Какое условие дергать я так и не понял.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: не понял комментарий. Стоит обновить вопрос [с небольшим, но полным примером кода, который используя искусственные данные, показал бы в чём проблема заключается](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример этого: "Можно рассмотреть подходит ли простой более высокоуровневый интерфейс, предоставляемый multiprocessing.ThreadPool. Или наоборот следует использовать threading.Condition напрямую:"

Comment: В чем вопрос? Не ясно для каких задач ThreadPool можно использовать? Или не ясно **как** использовать? Аналогично, для `threading.Condition`

Comment: Не ясно как вы хотите его использовать в данной ситуации.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: в вопросе не описана, что за ситуация. Описана  неудачная попытка решения, но сама проблема не указана. см. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096). Вот [пара](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16492930/4279) [примеров](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279) [кода](http://askubuntu.com/a/183315/3712).

Comment: Ситуация не описана в вопросе потому, что она имеет мало отношения к вопросу и абсолютно неинтересна тому кто придет сюда через поисковик. См. первый комент к этому ответу.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант:

```
while queue.empty():
    pass
print("Queue is not empty.")
```

У объекта Queue есть два условия (threading.Condition): `Queue.not_empty` и `Queue.not_full` можно попробовать использовать их, но с ними скорее всего будет проблема, что их использует сама очередь.

Comment: Busy waiting? Ага, простой (плюс они ничего не гаранируют). Кондишены я сам обнаружил, но они недокументированы.

Comment: Добавьте sleep(0.05) тогда поток будет отдавать управление системе и не будет грузить систему.

Comment: Я так и сделал, но это костылик.